# SSRS Report parameter not used when in the URL

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing

I want to send a parameter value to my SSRS report.  It is the name of the database to use.  I have tested the dynamic data source by creating a dropdown box to select the database when the parameter is not hidden.

I set the parameter setting on the report to 'Hide' under 'Manage' in the report.

I get the error:

> The 'DatabaseName' parameter is missing a value

I added the parameter value the URL:

`http://<serverName>/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fUDS+Reports%2fUDSTestDS%2fZipCodeDynamic&DatabaseName=Warehouse`

Why is it not reading the parameter value in the URL string?

Comment: Is `Warehouse` a valid *value* in the dropdown that you tested with? Or, did you remove the possible values before hiding the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the file path quite a bit to get it to work.
I needed **ReportServer?**
Also needed: **rs:Command=Render**

Hope this helps somebody...

```
http://serverName/ReportServer?%2fInitialFolderName%2fReportFolderName%2fReportName&rs:Command=Render&DatabaseName=Wrh1
```